The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string
In Django 5.0 I get the error:
The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string.
My code is:
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

app_name = 'AppServer_test'  # specified as string literal rather than a variable

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1.0/user/', include('user_accounts.urls')),
    path('api/v1.0/notifications/', include('notifications.urls')),
    path('api/v1.0/feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),
    # path('', include('AppServer_test.urls')),
    # check that AppServer_test.urls is a valid and accessible module
]

I've got the same code working in Django 3.2, the error only occurs in a system using 5.0
I've tried using round brackets instead of square as in this post:
Django 1.11 url pattern error, how to solve?
Traceback:
Invalid line: amqp://qtofknpw:j67JIAaQk-HzvM1-gjkYUD7GV1uSvy3O@elegant-cobalt-crow.rmq3.cloudamqp.com:5671/qtofknpw
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern 'AppServer_test.urls' is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.
HINT: Try removing the string 'AppServer_test.urls'. The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string as the first element.

App URL's:
Feedback App:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('submit/', views.submit_feedback, name='submit_feedback'),
]

Notifications App:
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import FetchNotificationReceipts, LogNotification, LogNotificationOpened, ResponderResponse, FetchNotificationReceipts

urlpatterns = [
    path('log-notification/', LogNotification, name='log_notification'),
    path('log-notification-opened/', LogNotificationOpened, name='log_notification_opened'),
    path('responder-response/', ResponderResponse, name='responder_response'),
    path('fetch-notification-receipts/', FetchNotificationReceipts, name='fetch_notification_receipts'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

User accounts App:
from django.urls import path
from .views import test

urlpatterns =[
    path('test/', test,name='test'),
   
]


That is not an error, but a warning iirc.

Please show us the traceback

Can you show us the source of the URLs you’re including? It could be the issue occurs within those instead.

@Lord Elrond I've added traceback and all urls.py files.

What's in your AppServer_test.urls ?  I suspect the error is in that file.

@Lord Elrond My understanding of AppServer_test.urls is that it's the first code snippet I posted?

Well, you are using include('AppServer_test.urls'), which means the url resolver is looking for a urls.py file in that app.  if that include is a reference to itself, then that is the problem.

Or is the error still raised with that line commented out?

@Lord Elrond Error is still raised after commenting  it out.
